# Is it possible for Keycloak user id across different realms to be duplicate?

Tags: keycloak

If we gather all users from all different realms of one Keycloak instance, is it possible for user id to be duplicate?

The screenshot of user ids I mentioned:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have a duplicate but extremely unlikely!
Keycloak uses UUIDs. Check “Random UUID probability of duplicates” section from [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Universally_unique_identifier&oldid=755882275#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates) Wikipedia article for details.